React native splash screen
Im new to react native. I build a react native apk using expo. When i try to open the app on my android device , after clicking the app icon a blank white screen comes, stays a second and then the splash screen comes. But i want it to instantly show the splash screen after clicking, not the empty white blank screen. How can i achieve that.Example. like you can see in the image. Right after clicking the splash screen shows up. I haven't added anything into the files. It's just a bare bone how we get after initializing a project with expo.
I deleted all the extra files in the project to see if it was related to them. but its still like that. I want it to behave like the expo go app when we open it.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
